# ¿Cómo recargar asíncronamente un tabla de bootstrap con ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap

Buen día, necesito que una tabla se refresque al momento de desactivar un registro

```
$.ajax({
        timeout: 30000, //30 segundos
        url:"ClientesCorp_Ctr/desactivar_contacto",
        type:"post",
        datatype:"json",
        data:{'desactivar':desactivar},
            error: function(){
                $('#no_respuesta').modal('show');//modal de error de respuesta
            },
            success:function(desactivar_contacto)
            {
                if(desactivar_contacto = true)
                {

                 desactivar_contacto = JSON.parse(desactivar_contacto);
                    $('#confirmar_eliminar').modal('hide');
                    //$('#table_contactos_cliente').bootstrapTable('refresh');
                     $('#tabla_cliente').bootstrapTable('load',desactivar_contacto); 
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Error');
                }
 



<div class="modal-body" style="padding-top: 1px;">
                <table id="table_contactos_cliente"
                    data-click-to-select="true"
                    data-search="true"
                    data-toolbar="#toolbar_table_contactos_cliente" 
                    data-url="tabla_cliente" 
                    data-single-select ="true"
                    data-search-on-enter-key="true"        
                    data-icons="icons"
                    singleSelect = "true"
                    data-height="450"  
                    data-maintain-selected = "false";
                    style="display: none"
                    class="table table-striped">
                    <thead class="bg-medium-gray">
                        <tr> 
                             <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                            <th data-field = "NOMBRE" data-sortable="false">NOMBREeeee</th>
                            <th data-field = "CORREO" data-sortable="false">CORREO</th>
                            <th data-field = "TELEFONO" data-sortable="false">TELEFONO</th>
                            <th data-field = "ID_CONTACTO" data-sortable="false" data-visible="false">ID</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

el id de la tabla es "#table_contactos_cliente"  pero no hace la función de refrescar luego de que se ejecuta la desactivación

se añadio mas codigo del lado de js para ver completo el codigo js y poder entender la ejecucion de la misma

Comment: ¿Y el código html lo puedes poner?  Es para ver si le has puesto el `data-url` tal como aparece en el ejemplo de [Bootstrap-Table](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#methods/refresh.html#view-source)

Comment: ya coloque el codigo de la tabla html

Comment: Siguen faltando datos. Mírate lo del [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), porque realmente así poco se te puede ayudar.  Además, sigo sin ver como rellenas la tabla... ¿te has mirado el ejemplo de mi comentario anterior? ¿donde esta el `data-url=` para rellenar la tabla de datos?  Si lo haces de otra forma indícalo, pues alli tendras el problema seguramente.

Comment: si coloco la etiqueta data-url al ejecutar el codigo me genera error ( supongo por el metodo de programacion que utulizan) ahy coloque mas codigo js y el de la tabla

Comment: Ha ocurrido un errror
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

Comment: No se que decirte, creo que tendria que rehacer todo el código porque o bien no tengo ni idea (que es posible) o estoy muy espeso (que también) o alli te has montado un lio gordo que parece un corta y pega a ver que pasa sin apenas sentido.  Suerte! (dejala abierta, quizas algun buen samaritano es capaz de poner orden sin reescribirla entera).

Comment: Para empezar, el código que has pasado no está ni terminado. La función de AJAX que has puesto está a medio escribir. Quieres ayuda? Danos algo que *COMPILE* (O ejecute en este caso), porque el error obvio que hay en tu pregunta ahora mismo es "A esa función le faltan corchetes de cierre". Añade algo funcional que podamos debugar para ayudarte, porque ni somos adivinos ni estamos sentados en tu silla, mirando tu código entero. Si tú eres incapaz de arreglarlo viéndolo entero... cómo puede otra persona arreglarlo viendo solo trozos sueltos??? Es imposible!